# How do I send PayPal the Craft Commerce Order Number?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ordering

The client is using PayPal Express for the payment gateway. When orders are placed, Paypal shows the ID for the order, not the Order Number. Is there somewhere I can change that?

Comment: Commerce 1 or 2-beta?

Comment: Commerce v1.2.1362, sorry.

Comment: I guess I also meant order.shortNumber since that's what appears in the Control Panel and on the order confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Commerce V1 - You can use a hooks for this:

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/hooks-reference#commerce_modifygatewayrequestdata

or

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/hooks-reference#commerce_modifypaymentrequest

...basically, start by dumping all the data to look at what is being sent, then modify it as you need.  Here's an example of something similar (I truncate the data to make sure it fits the gateway's limits):

```
    public function commerce_modifyGatewayRequestData($data,$type,$transaction){

        # Dump the data to see what is there....
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log("commerce_modifyGatewayRequestData"); 
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log("data");
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log($data);
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log("type");
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log($type);
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log("transaction");
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log($transaction);

        # TRUNCATE any over-sized data eWay might not like....
        # Data limits come from here: https://eway.io/api-v3/#direct-connection

       if(isset($data['Customer']['FirstName']))
        $data['Customer']['FirstName'] = substr($data['Customer']['FirstName'], 0, 49);

       ... etc

      return $data;
   }
```